# How can i see the sql statements in EJB 2.1 with CMP

Tags: sql, db2, ejb-2.x, cmp

I have an old EJB 2.1 project using DB2 as the database. 

I want to see the sql queries sent by the program to the database. How can i do that. I am using DB2. The persistency is container managed persistency.(`CMP`)

In Hibernate there is something like `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>` I want to have the same effect. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a suitable option for capturing SQL from your persistence layer, DB2 offers some powerful tracing options at the driver level and on the database server. Each approach has its pros and cons.

Since you've described the EJB project as being old, it's possible that your persistence layer is using IBM's JDBC Type 2 driver, which is essentially a wrapper around DB2's Call Level Interface, in which case you'd be looking at enabling tracing options through the db2cli.ini file.

The newer and more popular driver is the JDBC Type 4 "universal driver", db2jcc.jar, which handles tracing through properties that can be appended to the connection string and/or set at runtime by the application.

Since I work more with databases than with application servers, my personal preference for capturing SQL is to define a statement event monitor, which captures SQL statements and detailed statistics to a flat file or a set of dedicated tables. Event monitors offer a variety of filtering mechanisms that make it possible to collect detailed trace records for only a small portion of your total workload. Another attractive aspect of event monitors is that the DBA can start or stop them without disrupting the application server. Since event monitors can quickly collect a lot of data, I prefer using tables as event monitor targets because I can be easily analyze the results with a few SQL queries.